# OutOfMemoryError "com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.PendingJavaScriptInvocation - number of Objects(1663070)

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

After upgrading to version 23.2.x I began to receive periodically subj error. Is it just me or has anyone experienced this too?

**Thread stack**

```
https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-5
  at com.vaadin.flow.dom.Element$$Lambda$1668.get$Lambda(Lcom/vaadin/flow/component/internal/PendingJavaScriptInvocation;)Lcom/vaadin/flow/function/SerializableConsumer; (Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle$Holder.invokeStatic(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.invoke.Invokers$Holder.linkToTargetMethod(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (Unknown Source)
  at com.vaadin.flow.dom.Element.lambda$scheduleJavaScriptInvocation$9c7dc614$1(Lcom/vaadin/flow/internal/StateNode;Lcom/vaadin/flow/component/internal/PendingJavaScriptInvocation;Lcom/vaadin/flow/component/UI;)V (Element.java:1493)
  at com.vaadin.flow.dom.Element$$Lambda$1316.accept(Ljava/lang/Object;)V (Unknown Source)
  at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateNode.runWhenAttached(Lcom/vaadin/flow/function/SerializableConsumer;)V (StateNode.java:895)
  at com.vaadin.flow.dom.Element.scheduleJavaScriptInvocation(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/stream/Stream;)Lcom/vaadin/flow/component/page/PendingJavaScriptResult; (Element.java:1493)
  at com.vaadin.flow.dom.Element.callJsFunction(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/io/Serializable;)Lcom/vaadin/flow/component/page/PendingJavaScriptResult; (Element.java:1392)
  at com.vaadin.flow.component.combobox.ComboBoxDataController$UpdateQueue.lambda$enqueue$0(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/io/Serializable;)V (ComboBoxDataController.java:109)
  at com.vaadin.flow.component.combobox.ComboBoxDataController$UpdateQueue$$Lambda$1789.run()V (Unknown Source)
  at com.vaadin.flow.component.combobox.ComboBoxDataController$UpdateQueue$$Lambda$1793.accept(Ljava/lang/Object;)V (Unknown Source)
  at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Ljava/util/function/Consumer;)V (ArrayList.java:1541)
  at com.vaadin.flow.component.combobox.ComboBoxDataController$UpdateQueue.commit(I)V (ComboBoxDataController.java:103)
  at com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataCommunicator.passivateInactiveKeys(Ljava/util/Set;Lcom/vaadin/flow/data/provider/ArrayUpdater$Update;Z)V (DataCommunicator.java:1304)
  at com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataCommunicator.performUpdate(Ljava/util/Set;Lcom/vaadin/flow/internal/Range;Lcom/vaadin/flow/internal/Range;Lcom/vaadin/flow/data/provider/DataCommunicator$Activation;)V (DataCommunicator.java:1225)
  at com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataCommunicator.flush()V (DataCommunicator.java:1171)
  at com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataCommunicator.lambda$requestFlush$7258256f$1(Lcom/vaadin/flow/internal/ExecutionContext;)V (DataCommunicator.java:1103)
  at com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataCommunicator$$Lambda$1416.accept(Ljava/lang/Object;)V (Unknown Source)
  at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateTree.lambda$runExecutionsBeforeClientResponse$2(Lcom/vaadin/flow/internal/StateTree$BeforeClientResponseEntry;)V (StateTree.java:392)
  at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateTree$$Lambda$1720.accept(Ljava/lang/Object;)V (Unknown Source)
  at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Ljava/lang/Object;)V (ForEachOps.java:183)
  at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Ljava/lang/Object;)V (ReferencePipeline.java:177)
  at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Ljava/util/function/Consumer;)V (ArrayList.java:1655)
  at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Ljava/util/stream/Sink;Ljava/util/Spliterator;)V (AbstractPipeline.java:484)
  at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Ljava/util/stream/Sink;Ljava/util/Spliterator;)Ljava/util/stream/Sink; (AbstractPipeline.java:474)
  at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Ljava/util/stream/PipelineHelper;Ljava/util/Spliterator;)Ljava/lang/Void; (ForEachOps.java:150)
  at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Ljava/util/stream/PipelineHelper;Ljava/util/Spliterator;)Ljava/lang/Object; (ForEachOps.java:173)
  at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Ljava/util/stream/TerminalOp;)Ljava/lang/Object; (AbstractPipeline.java:234)
  at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Ljava/util/function/Consumer;)V (ReferencePipeline.java:497)
  at com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateTree.runExecutionsBeforeClientResponse()V (StateTree.java:389)
  at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlWriter.encodeChanges(Lcom/vaadin/flow/component/UI;Lelemental/json/JsonArray;)V (UidlWriter.java:390)
  at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlWriter.createUidl(Lcom/vaadin/flow/component/UI;ZZ)Lelemental/json/JsonObject; (UidlWriter.java:174)
  at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.createUidl(Lcom/vaadin/flow/component/UI;Z)Lelemental/json/JsonObject; (UidlRequestHandler.java:158)
  at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.writeUidl(Lcom/vaadin/flow/component/UI;Ljava/io/Writer;Z)V (UidlRequestHandler.java:146)
  at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(Lcom/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinSession;Lcom/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinRequest;Lcom/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinResponse;)Z (UidlRequestHandler.java:116)
  at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(Lcom/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinSession;Lcom/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinRequest;Lcom/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinResponse;)Z (SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
  at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(Lcom/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinRequest;Lcom/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinResponse;)V (VaadinService.java:1564)
  at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (VaadinServlet.java:364)
  at com.vaadin.cdi.CdiVaadinServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V (CdiVaadinServlet.java:67)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (HttpServlet.java:733)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljavax/servlet/FilterChain;)V (WsFilter.java:53)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V (ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (StandardContextValve.java:97)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (StandardHostValve.java:143)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (ErrorReportValve.java:92)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (RemoteIpValve.java:764)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V (StandardEngineValve.java:78)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(Lorg/apache/coyote/Request;Lorg/apache/coyote/Response;)V (CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketWrapperBase;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint$Handler$SocketState; (Http11Processor.java:374)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketWrapperBase;Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketEvent;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint$Handler$SocketState; (AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketWrapperBase;Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketEvent;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint$Handler$SocketState; (AbstractProtocol.java:888)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun()V (NioEndpoint.java:1597)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run()V (SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run()V (TaskThread.java:61)
  at java.lang.Thread.run()V (Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: It might be helpful if there was some more context, like a stack trace. Is it connected to a JavaScript invocation?

Comment: @ollitietavainen I can't post stack trace as comment - too long
I will send a separate message or fix the issue

Comment: That's great because the relevant information is supposed to be in the Question, not the comments.

Comment: Does it always die around that place? Is that number of objects something you feel responsible in your application? The trace contains a ComboBox class - are you following good practices with CB? From what version have you updated, that ran fine previously?  Can you provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: @cfrick this thread stack from heap dump which I received for the first time. When I tested with version 23.1.x I didn't get this kind of error. And of course I don't create that many ComboBox'es. In order to create an MRE, I need to roughly understand what is happening. But I have no idea. The maximum comes to mind, a large number of components. May be increase heap size?

Comment: I did not mean as many comboboxes but rather content of said comboboxes. How long (wall clock time) does ti take to end up with this error? If you don't think, you add this many things, could it be an infinite loop or something accumulating unbound?

Comment: @cfrick, The problem was resolved by revising the ui architecture - there were too many components in one view. Specifically, about 60 comboboxes with all countries + a small size of heap memory